# Adding length or each string in array and creating a new array with result appended

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need to do the following:

> Write a function that takes a String and returns an Array/list with the length of each word added to each element

Examples:

```
add_length('apple ban') => ["apple 5", "ban 3"]  
add_length('you will win') => ["you 3", "will 4", "win 3"]
```

I can find the length of each word but my question is, how do I then create a new array appending the lengths to each respective element? I think i need to use map again, but I am not sure how...

This is how I have worked out the lengths:

```
def add_length(str)  
   str.split(" ").map(&:length).to_s
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little modification could make it work:

```
'apple ban'.split(" ").map {|w| w + ' ' + w.length.to_s}
# => ["apple 5", "ban 3"]
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked, I was struggling with parameters

Answer (score 2):

You can use string interpolation to avoid string concatination and `to_s` calls. Futhermore there is no need for the `(" ")` argument when you use `split` to split strings at whitespaces:

```
def add_length(words)
  words.split.map { |word| "#{word} #{word.length}" }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `collect` method

```
def add_length(str)

   str.split(" ").collect { |e| e + ' ' + e.length.to_s }

end

p add_length('apple ban')
```

*Output:*

```
["apple 5", "ban 3"]
```